# NULL TO NOT NULL ALTER TABLE IN SAS

Tags: sas

I'm having difficulties running a SAS Data Intergration job.

One column needs to be removed from the target's structure,
but cannot be removed because of the NULL constraint.

Do I need to remove the constraint first?

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance,
Gal.

Answer (score 0):

Does the physical table exists without the column?  If so, then the constraint is only in the metadata.  Recreate the metadata and you should be fine.

If the physical table exists with the column, then you need to recreate that table without the column.  You will still need to refresh the table metadata for DI Studio to pick it up.